# Gated Push with Git in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, git-workflow, gated-checkin

Currently we use a dev-Branch in TFVC where every developer checks in. We have a Gated Checkin which ensures that our project builds.

Now we would like to switch to git, but TFS 2017 and Azure DevOps 2019 don´t have something similar to a Gated Checkin for git repositories. We could change our workflow to use feature branches and pull requests. But pull requests only test the code when merging to master (or another branch).

This would be okay if every feature is developed by a single developer. But in most of our features there work more than one developer on a feature. How could we prevent a developer from pushing code to a branch that breaks the build and blocks the other developers on the same branch?

Comment: I´m looking for a solution where not every developer needs his own branch. Maybe something like a pre-receive-hook, but build-in in TFS / Azure DevOps. I will wait a week or two if someone has any solution for this. If not, I will accept your answer. I think this is the way to work within git and we have to rethink our workflow.

Comment: How about the issue? Have you got any better solution this issue? After you reply, I have also tried more, but it seems that I have not found a better answer. I look forward to your reply.

Comment: No, I couldn´t find any better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could we prevent a developer from pushing code to a branch that breaks the build and blocks the other developers on the same branch?

We could use the Branch policies to protect the protect the feature branch.

[image]

To prevent a developer from pushing code to a branch that breaks the build and blocks the other developers on the same branch, like `Feature` branch.

We could add the [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) on the `Feature` branch to set a policy requiring changes in a pull request to **build successfully with the protected branch before the pull request can be completed**.

In this case, this Build validation will prevent a developer from pushing code to the `feature` branch that breaks the build and blocks the other developers on the `feature` branch.

When we have one more developers on this `Feature` branch, each developer should create their own branch based on the `Feature` branch, like `Feature_DevelopA`, whenever a developer merges to `Feature` branch, they need to pass the Build validation to complete the merge.

Besides, we could also add other Branch policies, like code reviewers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo, Build validation is fine but consider this scenario
PullRequest1 is created and a build is triggered as part of Build validation. This build is green (Compile + test cases etc.).
PullRequest2 is also in progress, which has some changes which may fail the first pull request changes. PullRequest2 build validation build is green and it is Approved and Completed and merged into master.
Now, pull request 1 is Approved (as it got a green build earlier) and completed and merged into master.
Once pull request1 changes are merged to master, master is now a broken branch. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply branch policies to your feature branches, just like you do with master.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you, but with branch policies on a feature branch also every developer has to work in his own branch :-(

Comment: Any reason why you can't make your developer branches short lived? Creating a new branch for each PBI or Task and then submitting a PR back to the feature branch is a standard workflow. Branching is much easier in Git than TFVC. You may want to look at some common git workflows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/use-git-microsoft